# Javascript canvas animation. Moving, growing and fading object

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Working on a project and cannot seem to get my animation right. I will not be showing the code because it simply doesn't work but it would be cool if someone were to give me a few pointers on how to animate a cloud of smoke moving upwards while slowly fading and increasing in size.

This effect should technically repeat once the y value reaches 0 i.o.w. the cloud reaches the top of the canvas.

What I need to know is how do I animate this, and which methods do I use. This is a kind of a self learning assignment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This is a kind of a self learning assignment* ... so, homework? Also, [please tell us what you have tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Set interval to a circle's x and y's position. Made an if statement saying that if y = 0, reset it's position. It basically creates an endless beam of growing proportions.

Teacher commented that there is a "better method" for this.
By the way this is just a quick step in the course and we have no book to refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jMfbx9Pif3oOqbhLRKDX?p=preview) of sprites growing in size and fading in transparency.

[image: Smoke Effect]

It is done using [Pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) which actually renders in webgl with a canvas fallback.  It should be possible to take the algorithm and apply it to raw canvas (although it would take some work).

```
var insertAfter = function(newNode, referenceNode) {
      referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

var range = function(aCount) {
  return new Array(aCount)
}

function main() {
    var el_main = document.getElementById("animation_main");

    var el_div = document.createElement('div');
    el_div.setAttribute('id', 'main_stage');
    insertAfter(el_div, el_main);

    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(300, 300, {
      transparent: true,
      antialias: true
    });
    el_div.appendChild(renderer.view);
    window.stage = new PIXI.Container();
    window.stage.x = 0;
    window.stage.y = 0;
    renderer.render(window.stage);

    var s = [];
    for (x of range(400)) {
      tCircle = new PIXI.Graphics();
      tCircle.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
      tCircle.s = (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
      tCircle.drawCircle(0, 0, 5 - tCircle.s);
      tCircle.x = Math.random() * 300
      tCircle.y = (Math.random() * 50) + 20
      tCircle.endFill();
      s.push(tCircle);
      window.stage.addChild(tCircle)
    }

    window.t = 0
    animate = function(t) {
      d = t - window.t
      window.t = t
      //Animation Start
      for (n in s){
        s[n].x += ((s[n].s / 25) * d)
        s[n].alpha = 1 - s[n].x / 300
        s[n].scale.x = 1 - s[n].alpha
        s[n].scale.y = 1 - s[n].alpha
        if (s[n].x > 300) {
          s[n].x = 0
          s[n].y = (Math.random() * 50) + 20
        }
      }
      renderer.render(window.stage)
      //Animation End
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){
      main();
  });
```

At the moment all of the tweening is linear ... it might look more realistic with a logarithmic or exponential tween ... but for simplicity i just left it as linear.

Answer (score 0):

Jakob Jenkov has done a really nice on-line book about canvas here:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/index.html

Since yours is a learning experience, I would just point you towards:

- **The basic workflow of html5 Canvas:** Anything drawn on the canvas cannot be altered, so all canvas animation requires repeatedly doing these things in an animation loop: (1) clearing the canvas, (2) calculating a new position for your objects, and (3) redrawing the objects in their new positions.
- **Animations:** `requestAnimationFrame` as a timing loop: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/efficient-animations-with-requestanimationframe
- **Transformations:** Canvas gives you the ability to scale, rotate and move the origin of its drawing surface.
- **Styling:** Canvas provides all the essential styling tools for drawing--including globalAlpha which sets opacity.

Comment: Thank you, quick question: are you able to use the alpha on one object in the canvass since global sounds like it affects it's entirety. Also how would I move, scale and alpha at the same time? same loop?

Comment: Check out Jenkov's book, it has all your answers. Yes, GlobalAlpha can be changed as you're drawing, so you could draw one thing at 100% opacity and then change globalAlpha to 50% for the next drawing. And yes, moving, scaling & alpha adjustments would all be put in the same animation loop. Good luck with your project!